# Any codes suggestion to be used in resizing for listview table?

Tags: c#, database, listview, resize

Any codes suggestion to be used in resizing for listview table?

I have a masterpage that contains a contentplaceholder. I have at least 5 tables in my database, I have currently created a webform that uses a table called member. I use the listview function to display the contents of my table. In that member table it contains at least 7 columns. When I debug the program, the table forces the contentplaceholder to resize making it bigger and not fitting to the design I want, so how do I resize my listview, so it will fit nicely in my design?

Comment: Yo might want to add some code so it'll be easier to help. What does it mean "fit nicely"?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - Also a link to an image might help..